Markov Chain Detailed Balance $\pi(x)*P(x, y) = \pi(y)*P(y, x)$
Let's say I have a Markov chain and it has a transition matrix denoted as $P$.  The $(row, column)$ elements of the $P$ matrix are denoted as $P(i, j)$.  Just by looking at the transition matrix $P$, how do I determine if it would satisfy the detailed balance equation $\pi(x)*P(x, y) = \pi(y)*P(y, x)$?  Sure, we could solve for the $\pi(x)'s$ plug in and check, but that would defeat the purpose here.  We want to know just by looking at $P$ if it will satisfy the detailed balance equation.
Under what conditions does $P$ satisfy the detailed balance equation?  We can determine things such as whether $P$ is irreducible, aperiodic, and so forth, but how do we determine satisfying detailed balance?
Thank you!

Why would checking the equation directly "defeat the purpose"?

Assume the chain is irreducible. The simplest necessary condition for the detail equations to hold is that $P_{ij}>0\iff P_{ji}>0$ for all $(i,j)$. You can often look at a chain to see this property immediately fails, meaning that the detail equations cannot hold. The simplest sufficient condition is that the chain is a birth-death chain (and that it has a steady state); you can often look at the chain to immediately see if the birth-death property holds. A necessary and sufficient condition for the detail equations is that the chain is reversible but it is not always easy to detect this.

For an irreducible $P$ such that $P(x,y)>0$ if and only if $P(y,x)>0$ (all pairs of states $x$ and $y$),   detailed balance hold for some reversibility measure $\pi$ if and only if Kolmogorov's loop condition holds: For each finite sequence of states $x_0, x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n=x_0$  you have
$$
 \prod_{i=1}^n P(x_{i-1},x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P(x_i,x_{i-1}).
$$
